# how to get android spinner value and store data in intent?

Tags: android

How to get value from the spinner array..and passing the value to next page using the intent. THis is my spinner and string.xml. Please give me some advise. Thank you

//spinner list

```
 private String foodorder;

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, **R.array.food_array**, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);   
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(foodList);

Button search_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        search_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent it = new Intent();
            it.setClass(searchfood.this, search_displayResult.class);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("KEY_DEPARTURE", ); //what should i put here?


            }
        });

}
    private Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener foodList = new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener () {
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
                 foodorder = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
             }
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

             }
     };
```

String.xml

```
<string name="food_prompt">Choose a food</string>
    <string-array name="food_array">   
        <item>Fish Burger</item>
        <item>French Fried</item>
        <item>Beef Burger</item>
        <item>Chicken Burger</item>
        <item>Salad</item>

    </string-array>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this code in `OnItemSelected` method.

```
String item = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("item",item);
startActivity(intent);
```